# Approve document by multiple people: is it possible to do it without a 'task'?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

When you have a document approval process by multiple people I have always used the standard approval workflow provided with sharepoint (the 2010 template one).

As you know this one is based on the 'task' to collect the approved/rejected feedback and change the status of the file accordingly.

Has anyone done this workflow without the 'task' process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft Flow - there is a flow/action for "Starting an approval" which should offer you an alternative way to build an approval process

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using custom list and add workflow. Also you can use impersonate steps to manage unique permission.